# How to set image size within parent td width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to set image size within parent td width? The image may vary dynamically.

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need a bit more explanation. What have you tried? Any source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var imgs = $('img');

imgs.each(function() {
  var pwidth = $(this).parent('td').width();
  $(this).attr('width',pwidth);
});
```

You can also use css:

```
img {width: 100%}
```

So that the image will automatically get the width of its parent

Comment: Thanks. If the image below the td width it should not resize. for example td width=70% image width inside that td is 100%

Comment: @anglimass : you should explain more!

Comment: Use the CSS; it's more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already have this code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbZEy/1/) . would you please give more detail